# What is "One Piece" called in Japanese?

Tags: one-piece, japanese-language

- Attack on Titan = Shingeki no Kyojin
- Food Wars = Shokugeki no Soma
- Jojo's Bizarre Adventure = JoJo no Kimyou na Bouke
- Darker Than Black = Kuro no Keiyakusha
- Fighting Spirit = Hajime no Ippo
- Assassination Classroom = Ansatsu no Kyoushitsu
- Code Geass: Lelouch of the Rebellion = Code Geass: Hangyaku no Lelouch
- One Piece - ?

See what I mean?

What is "One Piece" known as in Japanese?

Comment: One Piece in Japan is known as WanPiisu :)

Comment: ワ{wa}ン{n}ピー{pii}ス{su}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[As confirmed by MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/21/One_Piece), *One Piece* is still known as *One Piece* in Japanese.

While you've provided plenty of examples of anime whose English names are translated from the original Japanese, *One Piece* is not the only anime whose Japanese name is in English. *Black Lagoon*, *Angel Beats*, *Death Note*, and *Summer Wars* are other prominent examples.

Comment: This is really simple and makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: The One Piece Wiki has some more details on the name and translation too: "In the original manga, the term "One Piece" (ワンピース Wan Pīsu?) is often accompanied by an additional string of text translating roughly to "the great hito-tsunagi treasure" (ひとつなぎの大秘宝 Hito-tsunagi no Dai-hihō?), initially as a separate descriptor[7] and later as a base-text directly glossed with the "One Piece" katakana."

https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/One_Piece